# react js dynamic routing show only white page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want it to be dynamic routing I but the Rout method in a list only show a white page

MasterLayout.js

```
const MasterLayout = () => {
      return (
                 <main>

                    <Routes>
                        {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                            return (
                                route.component && (
                                    <Route
                                        key={idx}
                                        path={route.path}
                                        exact={route.exact}
                                        name={route.name}
                                        render={(props) => (
                                   <route.component {...props} />
                             )}
                          />
                         )
                       )
                   })}
              <Navigate from="/admin" to="/admin/dashboard" />
           </Routes>
        </main>
  )
}
```

the list of the routes like this

route.js

```
const routes = [
    
    { path: '/admin', exact: true, name: 'Admin'},
    { path: '/admin/dashboard', exact: true, name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard },
    { path: '/admin/profile', exact: true, name: 'Profile',  component: Profile },

];
```

in App.js like this I dont what the problem

```
<div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>          
        <Route path="/admin" name="Admin" render={(props)=> <MasterLayout {...props} /> } />
          {/* <Route path="/admin" Component={MasterLayout} /> */}
        </Routes>
      </Router>
</div>
```

im new in react js sorry if i cant show the exact problem